# How we can hide tabs on detail page in xamarin form?

Tags: c#-4.0, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Currently I am removing tabs and add again but still there is space top which not looks nice is there any other way thanks.

Comment: Please show your code, so others can reproduce your problem and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

var page = new NavigationPage(new Page1());

await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(page, true);